# How to call setTextContent in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to re write xml file using jdom, i got some example in goodle, they used setTextContent to append value in xml tag. but android is not supporting node.setTextContent. instead of this what is the key word for accessing setTextContent. if anyone did this issue pls let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no xxxTextContent() methods in org.w3c.dom.Element.

A Text Node is just like any other node in xml. You'll need to find the Text node child of your element, and use setNodeValue().

Something like this:

```
node.getFirstChild().setNodeValue(newValue);
```

Comment: Thank you dude, This is the first time i am parsing xml through java. thanks for your proper guidance.